# C# Intersect Two Dictionaries and Store The Key and The Two Values in a List

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, intersect

I want to intersect the 2 dictionaries, but I am not sure how to store historicalHashTags[x] too, I managed to store only the key and value of 1 dictionary.

```
var intersectedHashTags = currentHashTags.Keys.Intersect(historicalHashTags.Keys).
ToDictionary(x => x, x => currentHashTags[x]);
```

But, I want the result to be stored in a list that includes Key, currentHashTags[x], and historicalHashTags[x]

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> currentHashTags = 
{ ["#hashtag1", 100], ["#hashtag2", 77], ["#hashtag3", 150], ...} 
Dictionary<string, int> historicalHashTags = 
{ ["#hashtag1", 144], ["#hashtag4", 66], ["#hashtag5", 150], ...} 

List<(string,int,int)> result = { ["#hashtag1", 100, 144] }
```

Comment: Can you present a working minimalist sample that creates the actual data for the Dictionary?

Comment: I have updated the answer with example to be more clear

Comment: I suspect you want to Intersect to use the same `IEqualityComparer` as the dictionaries but, what if they differ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep only the elements common to both dictionaries, you can use the `Intersect` method of type `Dictionary` on their keys. Then with `Select` method you transform this result into an `IEnumerable<(string, int, int)>`. Finally convert it to a list.

```
Dictionary<string, int> currentHashTags = new()
{
    {"#hashtag1", 11},
    {"#hashtag2", 12},
    {"#hashtag3", 13},
    {"#hashtag4", 14}
};
Dictionary<string, int> historicalHashTags = new()
{
    {"#hashtag2", 22},
    {"#hashtag3", 23},
    {"#hashtag4", 24},
    {"#hashtag5", 25}
};

List<(string, int, int)> intersectedHashTags = currentHashTags.Keys
    .Intersect(historicalHashTags.Keys)
    .Select(key => (key, currentHashTags[key], historicalHashTags[key]))
    .ToList();
// Content of intersectedHashTags:
// ("#hashtag2", 12, 22)
// ("#hashtag3", 13, 23)
// ("#hashtag4", 14, 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionaries are of type `Dictionary<string, string>` and you want `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as output, then this works:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> combinedHashTags =
    currentHashTags
        .Concat(historicalHashTags)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

To get the intersection a simple join would work:

```
List<(string Key, int current, int historical)> combined =
(
    from c in currentHashTags
    join h in historicalHashTags on c.Key equals h.Key
    select (c.Key, c.Value, h.Value)
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, No, my Dictionary is Dictionary<string, int>, i want the result to be List<string, int, int>, where string is the intersected key that is a unique value, int is currentHashTags values and int is historicalHashTags values.

Comment: @bobmason The type `List<string, int, int>` doesn't exist, did you mean `List<(string, int, int)>`, so a list of tuples? If so, you lost properties of dictionaries (i.g. access elements in O(1) time)

Comment: yes sorry, List<(string, int, int)> , there are no lost properties, as the string is the intersected key between the 2 dictionaries, and the other 2 ints are the 2 dictionaries values, and that's all that I need.